# Is it possible to combine parametrized tests with non-parametrized in jUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

The use case is as follows, I would like to be able to combine parametrized and non parametrized test as well as have different parameters for different parametrized tests.

Using [Parameterized.class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26525585/2339141) seems a bit of an overkill as this will blow up the constructor for each new unit test I need to parametrize, also will result in multiple runs of the non parametrized tests which I am not interested in.

So I was thinking about [Theories.class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/752578/2339141) , but although multiple `@DataPoint`s can be provided, those refer to individual types passed as each argument to the test function and still results in only one function tested.

I would like to achieve something like

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
class Test{
    @Theory(named="foo")
    public void fooTest(Object input) { 
    }

    public static @DataPoints(named="foo") Object[] inputs = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    @Theory(named="bar")
    public void barTest(Object input) { 
    }

    public static @DataPoints(named="bar") Object[] inputs = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    public void bazTest() {
    }
}
```

Where `fooTest` is tested with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and `barTest` with `6, 7, 8, 9, 10` respectively.

Is there a way to achieve that using `Theory`s? Is there any alternative to achieve that?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to create two different test classes for that.
You can also switch to TestNG which allows this.

Comment: @tamasrev switching to anything else is not rly an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix test style with the Theories runner. But some third party parameterised runners such as [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) could be used in this way.

e.g

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

  @Test
  @Parameters({"17, false", 
               "22, true" })
  public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
    assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(valid));
  }

  @Test
  public void lookNoParams() {
    etc
  }

}
```

Comment: I am really looking for an option that uses the out of the box functionality provided by jUnit, alternatives are more for general knowledge improvement.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 5 introduced `ParameterizedTest` ([doc](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5)):

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {2, 4, 6})
public void isEven(Integer val) {
    assertTrue(val % 2 == 0);
}
```

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5) is a nice tutorial.